# А personal attitude towards me or not

Tags: support

I would like to ask if the following is a personal attitude towards me. I observe downvotes on all of my answers. Is it about reputation points, as it just looks like something personal?

Can someone confirm or deny?

Comment: it's probably the beard.... always get downvotes if your pic has a beard

Answer (score 5):

Nobody has visibility of who votes for what, as it should be, so confirmation is not possible.

Of your 3 posts, I can see why one has a downvote - I would probably have done that as well, as it is very difficult to read. Another seems to make a point that is debatable, so people can up or downvote as regards their experience.

You'll find that people don't tend to vote on people (and where they do, the automated anti-fraud systems catch this and reverse it) and instead they vote on posts.

With only 3 posts so far, I wouldn't worry about it. They currently sit at net 2, 0 and -1. No major issues.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications. And in your words I see another point, favoritism of native speakers. If post is hard to read maybe some comments for clarification will improve the situation :)

Comment: @Romeo - that is true. When downvoting for a specific reason, it can be very helpful to leave a comment as to why, especially for new members of the community. However, comments are not mandatory, so without them a downvote just means "this answer is not useful" as per the tooltip

Comment: And one more point. Because downvotes happen in less than minute there is (IMO) very low probability two or tree persons did it

Comment: These things are always possible, but seriously, don't worry about it - you have a total of 4 upvotes and 3 downvotes give you a net gain of 34 points (+10 for upvote, -2 for downvote)